# How to hide a bootstrap card when dropped in a landing zone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using vanilla javascript for a drag and drop. I drag a bootstrap card
and drop in a landing zone. Once I drop it, I want to hide it and not show
it. I will later show it on Mouse over where I dropped it.

How can I hide the dropped card? I assume it will be done in the onDrop function

```js
function onDrop(event) {
  var id = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");

  //select our draggable element with the id we retrieved
  var draggableElement = document.getElementById(id);

  //select our dropzone element
  var dropzone = event.target;

  //Append our draggable element to the dropzone
  dropzone.appendChild(draggableElement);

  //Hide the draggable element
  //draggableElement.draggable.hide(); ???

  //reset our datatransfer object
  event.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the DOM after the element is dropped. You can do some CSS to hide the element.

```css
.droppedItem{ 
    display:none;
}
```

And on mouseover do

```css
.droppedItem{ 
    display:block;
}
```